# Symmetrical table, is booktabs recommended?

Tags: booktabs

I have the following table, used with `booktabs`.  I call it "symmetric" as three states of two variables are compared, but it does not matter if a variable is written along the rows or along the columns.  It is not a some variables (columns) describing observations (rows), but two variables and their correlation.  I may also invert "X → Y" and "Y → X", it would be the same).

In this situation, using `booktabs` and its strict guidelines (especially “never, ever use vertical rules”) does not really make sense.  Why is there a line below "X → Y" variable labels and not at right of "Y → X" variable labels?

What is the recommended way of displaying such a table?  Should I use `booktabs` at all in this specific situation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Quality of links, one way versus the other}
  \begin{tabular}{llccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$X \rightarrow Y$} \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    & & good & uncertain & weak \\
    \midrule
    & good & 32 & 12 & 2 \\
    $Y \rightarrow X$
    & uncertain & 13 & 52 & 5 \\
    & weak & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, your table structure is symmetric logically [or perhaps mathematically ?...though the values does not depict a symmetric matrix where, say, (good, weak) is 2, but (weak, good) is 4 !] The `booktabs` guidelines are for visual comfort and professional look. You can see any scientific journal article, where vertical lines are never used. They impair reading flow. To summarize: your table looks perfect.

Comment: @ParthaD. Yep, I understand why `booktabs` provides these guideline.  The question is, does they really applies here?  Doesn't they break signification (and readability) of the table, with "X→Y"'s labels separated from the data while "Y→X"' labels aren't?  —  Don't worry about mathematical symmetry, the table effectively does not really have mathematical sense, because of details missing in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well…

- Either you and don't worry of the semantic equivalence between "X→Y" and "Y→X", and you are just presenting a table.  Then `booktabs` rules are OK, your code is OK, and Bernard's design is cool.
- Or you absolutely want to separate your numbers from the labels and be "symmetric" (i.e. do the same formatting between "X→Y" and "Y→X"), **and you accept breaking the `booktabs` rules**; then put two tiny vertical rule (`cmidrule`'s equivalent) between the 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> columns.
- Or, just do not put any rule in the table, just keep the `toprule` and the `bottomrule` (they are not annoying).  You may need to put a little more space between column labels and following lines, as shown there.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{skip=4pt}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Quality of links, one way versus the other}
    \begin{tabular}{llccc}
      \toprule
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$X \rightarrow Y$} \\
      %\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
      & & good & uncertain & weak \\
      %\midrule
      \addlinespace
      & good & 32 & 12 & 2 \\
      $Y \rightarrow X$
      & uncertain & 13 & 52 & 5 \\
      & weak & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image: example of table]

Answer (score 3):

There can be some minor improvements (from my point of view): trimming the `\cmidrule`, a slightly larger spacing between the last 3 rows, and a larger spacing between caption and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\captionsetup{skip =4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Quality of links, one way versus the other}
  \begin{tabular}{llccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$X \rightarrow Y$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
    & & good & uncertain & weak \\
    \midrule
    & good & 32 & 12 & 2 \\[2pt]
    $Y \rightarrow X$
    & uncertain & 13 & 52 & 5 \\[2pt]
    & weak & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the design!